# Nestjs with pm2, port still be used after killing the process with pm2 stop?

Tags: nestjs, pm2

I deployed my Nest.js application on my VPS (Ubuntu 20.04 DO) using [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) as process manager. Here is my step by step when I'm updating the app.

```sh
$ pm2 stop 1
$ kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:4040)
$ npm run build
$ pm2 start 1
```

Notice that I must kill the port that the app use before I proceed to the build one, how to simplify it and become like these :

```sh
$ npm run build
$ pm2 reload 1
```

So I can deploy my Nest.js app gracefully and achieve at least only 1% downtime

Comment: I used pm2. Did you hear from docker? Much easier and fixes a lot of problems.

Comment: I considered using docker too, Let me explore it

Comment: Try `killall node && npm run build && pm2 reload 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop command keeps the app in the apps list while the delete command not.

I think you want something like

`start.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source .env
ENVIRONMENT="$NODE_ENV"
npm run build || exit
pm2 delete "$ENVIRONMENT"
pm2 start "npm run start:prod" --name "$ENVIRONMENT" --log-date-format 'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS'
```

If you are not using different environments, an equivalent script would be

```sh
#!/bin/bash
npm run build || exit
pm2 delete my_application
pm2 start "npm run start:prod" --name my_application --log-date-format 'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS'
```

Emitting the `--log-date-format` is perfectly fine. However, I have included it because I suspect it might become helpful when finding bugs in production down the line.